# What is the name of this technique of returning multiple values from a function in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, function, multiple-return-values

```
Protected Function ammountChanges(order As BasicSimpleOrder, createOrDelete As Boolean) As (change As Decimal, currency As String)


End Function
```

I sort of know that it's possible and I want to learn more about it.

However, if I search in google for

```
function returning multiple values vb.net
```

for example,

or in stackoverflow

no body is mentioning that technique.

Even if I search for

```
function returning multiple values through anonymous type
```

people are still using different techniques.

Now I think it's a new feature.

Basically, you "can't" really return multiple values. You can return a class or a struct and that class or struct can contain multiple values.

However, recent vb.net improvement allow a convenient way to allow an anonymous type as return values.

However, I cannot find any reference to that method anywhere on the net. Not easily. Not with the keyword I found.

So where is it, and what should I search in google to learn more about this feature.

Comment: It's [```Tuples```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples) introduced in [Visual Basic 15 / Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/whats-new/#visual-basic-15)

Comment: @HelO'Ween just post it as an actual Answer since it solves the question. You should also mention that they should especially [read this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples#tuples-as-method-return-values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples) introduced in [Visual Basic 15 / Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/whats-new/#visual-basic-15).

See the section: [Tuples as method return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples#tuples-as-method-return-values) where it mentions (with code examples):

> A method can return only a single value. Frequently, though, you'd
> like a method call to return multiple values. There are several ways
> to work around this limitation:
>
> - You can create a custom class or structure whose properties or fields represent values returned by the method. This is a heavyweight
>   solution; it requires that you define a custom type whose only purpose
>   is to retrieve values from a method call.
> - You can return a single value from the method, and return the remaining values by passing them by reference to the method. This
>   involves the overhead of instantiating a variable and risks
>   inadvertently overwriting the value of the variable that you pass by
>   reference.
> - You can **use a tuple**, which provides a **lightweight solution** to **retrieving multiple return values**.

Comment: So the type is really just simple "Tuples"?